# Firebase - how to run a query and an update on a document in one transaction

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

My problem is that transactions only allow to `delete`, `get`, `set` and `update` documents.

For a 2 player game I need to create games and to join a game. The idea is following:

- check if a game without opponent exists => join it if I find one
- create a new game if no game without opponent exists

This means, that the query that searches for a game without opponent and updates it runs in a transaction. How can I do this?

**Problem:**

*What if the game did change in the meantime (between query and update) and was updated already? I currently possibly override some other player who has joined the game in the meantime... How can I solve this problem?*

**Code**

This is what I have so far:

```
// get a game without opponent
var gameQueryRef = db.collection('games')
    .where('state', '==', '1')
    .limit(1);

return gameQueryRef.get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
        var gameRef = null;
        if (querySnapshot.docs.length === 0) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return querySnapshot.docs[0].ref;   
        }
    })
    .then(gameRef => {
        log("GameRequest", gameRequestId, "gameRef = " + gameRef);
        if (gameRef === null)
        {
            var newGameRef = db.collection("games").doc();
            var game = {
                state: 1,
                creationDate: Date.now(),
                finishDate: 0,
                docPlayer1: docPlayer,
                docPlayer2: null
            };
            return newGameRef.set(game);
        }
        else
        {
            // update game => THIS IS NOT SAVE!
            // what if the game did change in the meantime and was updated already????
            // I possibly override some other player who has joined this game in the meantime...
            return gameRef.update(state => 2, docPlayer2 => docPlayer);
        }
    })
    // continue with game
```

**EDIT - Solution**

I posted a possible solution I will test, if someone has a comment on this I'm interested in this as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Possible solution idea**

Document ids can be defined manually and must be unique within one collection only, so we can simply make the same document in another collection.

So I will create a collection that I call `GameLocks`.

With this idea I think following does work:

- I query a game and get the `Game`'s document => sadly outside of the transaction, so I need to recheck the game's state within the transaction to be sure nothing changed between the query and the transaction
- Then I start a `transaction` with following steps:

  - check if a `GameLocks` document exists (via `transaction.get`) that has the same id as the `Game` document => if true, I know someone else is already trying to join this game and I can handle this and so I stop this transaction here (either I search for another game or I simply start a new game without opponent and wait for someone else to join this game)
  - no `GameLock` document exists, so I create one => I simply take the `Game`'s id for the lock as well
  - check if the game is still a valid target => does it still not have an opponent? (via `transaction.get`) => important, as we have not been in an transaction when the query was executed! => end transaction, if someone else already joined this game
  - update the game (via `transaction.update`)
  - delete the `GameLock` document again (via `transaction.delete`)
  - finish the transaction

By running the `create` and `delete` operation of the lock document in a transaction and doing the check of the `Game` and all the manipulations in between them, I can be sure noone else can manipulate the same `Game` document in between and so this should solve the problem.